# Comments on close-vote review test questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits

A couple of times recently I've tried to add a comment to a question before making my close-vote, only to discover that this was only a test and that the question had been closed days or weeks or months ago. Now I've left a comment far too late to be useful, so I've had to go and delete it.

Is this really desirable behaviour? I'm sure on some other review tasks hitting the 'add comment' button reveals that it was just a test before I've started typing.

Comment: yeah, that shouldn't be possible in review audits. looking

Comment: Did you failed the audit because of this?

Comment: @A.L no, the action of adding a comment has no effect on close voting. I only noticed because I often leave a comment as well as voting.

Comment: @Rook : I asked this because I [failed an audit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/6316729), I posted a comment before performing any action and it failed.

Comment: @A.L that hasn't happened to me, but then I haven't commented on anything that turned to be an audit since I posted this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments in review audits do not propagate to the actual posts anymore, since some data is tempered with when preparing post-to-be-audit for display.

Comment: And commenting something on test questions should not result in `Whoa you commented on a nice question pal you were not paying attention`. Got this on https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/26606602